# stopCellEditing on JDialog

Tags: java, swing

My question is similar to this one: [JTable Cell Update doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951297/jtable-cell-update-doesnt-work).

However, I am using JDialog instead of a JTable specified in above link. I have a custom class which extends JDialog. I use JEditorPane as a text-component in that dialog and create simple OK, Cancel buttons. Now the problem is, when I enter something in the JEdiorPane and presses OK button, the value is not applied to the text-component until I move the focus out of a JDialog or hit tab/ENTER.

I want the container to be notified that I am done with editing as soon as I press the OK button. In short I want to explicitly have a feature similar to stopCellEditing(). How can I do that?

Comment: *"How can I do that?"* You supply a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem...because that sounds all wrong to me.  What you type into a text component is committed to the document at the time you write it...

Answer (score 1):

See this example which seems to work correctly and does the same thing as you described:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestEditorPaneDialog {

    public void init() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JButton clickMe = new JButton("Click me");
        clickMe.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                showDialog(frame);
            }
        });
        frame.add(clickMe);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        showDialog(frame);
    }

    private void showDialog(final JFrame frame) {
        final JDialog dialog = new JDialog(frame, true);
        final JEditorPane pane = new JEditorPane();
        pane.setText("Type something here");
        JPanel south = new JPanel();
        JPanel buttons = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0, 10, 10));
        JButton ok = new JButton("OK");
        ok.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                dialog.dispose();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "You have typed in: " + pane.getText());
            }
        });
        JButton cancel = new JButton("Cancel");
        cancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                dialog.dispose();
            }
        });
        buttons.add(ok);
        buttons.add(cancel);
        south.add(buttons);
        dialog.add(new JScrollPane(pane));
        dialog.add(south, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        dialog.setSize(250, 150);
        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(frame);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestEditorPaneDialog().init();
            }
        });
    }
}
```